# Sitecore Rich Text Editor Custom classes add/Path

Tags: richtext-editor

Where to see the custom classes that are showing in the Sitecore Rich Text Editor.
(path in core database)

I just want another class here. where to add this?

We are not using the ToolsFile.xml file.

I'm using Sitecore 9.3

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. In `web.config` file check the value of setting WebStylesheet. By default, it is “`/default.css`“. Open this file & add your css classes in this file
2. In the `ToolsFile.xml` file located at rootfolder\sitecore\shell\Controls\Rich Text Editor\ folder and add css class entries in `<classes>` node
3. Navigate to `rich text editor` field of your template and make sure the source property of it is set to either Rich Text Full or Rich Text Medium

OR you can follow the steps listed here :- https://therelentlessfrontend.com/2018/03/15/adding-custom-css-class-to-sitecore-rich-text-editor/

OR you can follow :-  https://learnsitecorebasics.wordpress.com/2015/03/17/apply-css-classes-in-rich-text-editor/

Comment: No. In the helix solution or core database where I need to add that class. In the above article they are adding in the toolsxml file. But helix solution doesn't have that file.

Comment: You can have the same hierarchy under your project node in helix solution